# Sharing certain item on Facebook and twitter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter based website. There are some certain products in my website. I want to add 2 buttons (facebook and twitter only) for each product. When user click the button, he will be able to share that item on facebook or twitter. How can I do that? I have experienced in addthis and sharethis.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Facebooks **[Share-Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)** (it's deprecated - the **[Like-button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)** is the better solution) and Twitters **[Tweet-Button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton)**